# awk updating to txt

Tags: linux, awk

i have this code which is working but the result is not updated to my alpha.txt. is there anyway i can do it? im trying to change my 2nd e into f using variables.
a,b,c,d,e,e

```
  awk -F',' -v n="$line" -v na="$newalpha" 'NR==n{$6=na;}1' OFS="," alpha.txt
```

Comment: `awk` does not have an option for inplace editing. Pipe the result into a temporary file.

Comment: Thanks alot. was searching for an answer for 2 days and i finally got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect it, like:

```
awk -F',' -v n="$line" -v na="$newalpha" '
    NR==n{$6=na;}1
' OFS="," alpha.txt >/tmp/alpha.txt && mv /tmp/alpha.txt alpha.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

try this: (better backup first)

```
awk -F',' '...yourScript..' alpha.txt > /tmp/alpha.tmp && mv /tmp/alpha.tmp alpha.txt
```